# Make a telephone link that directly sends you to the dial app

Tags: html, mailto, tel

I'm currently developing a mobile app and I want to make a link which when clicked will automatically send me to the dial pad. Right now, using `<a href="tel"... >`, when I click on the link I get a selection of apps with which I can open it, what I'd like to happen is when I click on the link to be directly redirected to the default dial pad, without the extra clicking. The same applies for email links, currently doing it with `<a href="mailto..>`. Is there any way you can do that?

Comment: I think there no option in html to trigger the dialpad. This article may help you https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

Answer (score 1):

This is a default functionality of the mobile operating system. If you have just one app that tries to read the "tel:" protocol event, then you'll directly go to that app. But in case there are multiple apps that listen to the "tel:" protocol, then you'll be served with the choices.